# Does a running engine lose material?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, atoms

I'm not sure if this is the right stack exchange to ask this, but I was thinking the other day about a running engine. As it heats up do the atoms in the engine block become more excited? If so, does an engine (in my case I was thinking about a motorcycle) slowly lose atoms? If you could theoretically run the engine long enough would it disintegrate because the block gets thinner?

I am guessing that an iron block doesn't lose atoms because of the arrangement of them being a solid. But, if you leave an ice cube alone even in subfreezing temperatures it can sublimate and eventually disappear right? Is there a process that prevents a metal engine block from doing the same thing even if it's a much slower process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does a metal evaporate in a solid phase? Theoretically yes, but extremely slow. Practically no. You can run your engine for thousands of years and not detect any weight loss specifically for this reason.

The physics here is that an atom would need a certain energy to detach and run away. In the solid metal state, the energy of the bonding between the atoms is higher than the average thermal energy. Therefore atoms normally would not detach.

However, there could be a coincidence when an atom receives a "push" simultaneously from several neighbors, and the combined energy may exceed the bonding energy thus pushing the atom away. Such conditions would have an extremely low probability resulting in a negligible loss of material over any reasonable time frame.

Your piston rings wearing off the cylinder liners is what you probably worry about instead :)

Comment: To summarize, there are probably a non-zero number of iron atoms that have left an engine but it's a small enough number to be irrelevant. The heat of the engine is not enough energy to overcome the bonds of the metal the vast majority of the time? When I worked in a forge with glowing 2500 degree steel would that have been enough heat to notice any atoms leaving?

Comment: Probably no. What you might notice in that case would be the surface oxidation. While oxidation would increase the mass due to the addition of oxygen, the oxide is not nearly as strong as the metal and can easily fall off thus reducing the total mass. Depends on specific conditions. You would not have a notisable mass reduction due to evaporation *at least* until the metal is melted.

Comment: I understand that there are other things that you'd notice first. I had just wondered if metal atoms would leave the metal at all. Thank you for the answer.